# Creating generic comment model in Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, laravel-5

I have a comments table that can be useful im many parts of the project, not only in photos, for example. Is there a way to implement a generic Comment model/table that can process where a comment should be shown?

Is this a good idea or I should separate the comments for each area of the site? Like **comments_photos**, **comments_songs**, **comnents_videos**, and so on?

Thanks.

Comment: this is exactly what you are looking for http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @pinkalvansia I read the Answer for my question and started to think about it. Maybe store lots of comments in one table is not the best idea. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes you can create generic comments as `@pinkal vansia` mentioned using polymorphic relations.

But in my humble opinion I wouldn't store all comments in a single table. One of the reasons for that would be performance. If you're going to have lot's of comments where each row will have it's own type. This such table will result in bigger table size and will need additional indexes to perform well.

Also you should keep in mind that Laravel's ORM does not always suffice the needs. Then you have to write manual SQL, which is going to be more complex.

And the main reason I'd be against it is because there would be only couple of corner cases where you would need to work with all the comments in the system instead of single type. So therefore you would need to check for correct type of comment each time you do something with it. So in my opinion it breaks KISS principle without a good reason.

Comment: I see your point @insanebits. I'll keep the KISS principle then. Thanks for the help!